# Use same rewrite rule for every parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a file named dev.php which has 5 parameters. It's a step by step procedure where the same file will be used and the result will be based on each of the parameters. Let me be more clear with an example.

```
http://www.example.com/dev.php?a=1&b=10&c=100&d=1000&e=10000
```

First, the user has to choose an option based on which they will be redirected to the next page.

I am using this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /dev.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3&d=$4&e=$5 [L]
```

It works fine when all the five parameters are present in the query, but throws a 404 error when there are 1-4 parameters. I want the Rewrite Rule to make this work even if 1 parameter is passed.

Sorry for the weird heading. I don't have any idea in what way I should ask the question.

Answer (score 0):

If the RewriteRule's template doesn't exactly match the SEO-form URI that was input, there will be no rewrite, and the server will attempt to load `/1/10/100/1000` which doesn't exist (and thus the 404). One way to fix it is to have 5 RewriteRules, one for one parameter given, one for two, etc. Only one of them should match. Check that the final result /dev.php... doesn't trip any of the rewrites -- you might put the single match first, then the two parameters, etc. Also consider making an optional / on the last parameter, since users will often type it in.